# Python binance API errors

Tags: python, binance

When I try to work with the Binance API I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lironmeir/Documents/Py/trad/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from binance import Client, ThreadedWebsocketManager, ThreadedDepthCacheManager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/binance/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from binance.client import Client, AsyncClient  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/binance/client.py", line 3, in <module>
    import aiohttp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'
```

The library installed in the right folder and everything is fine but something went wrong somewhere and I just can't manage to work with the API.

Comment: Did you install using `pip`? Or by just downloading it? You're missing the dependency, `pip/pip3 install aiohttp`

Comment: i did installed it using pip i dont even know where this aiohttp came from i dont see nothing about it in the binance docs

Answer (score 0):

The "aiohttp" library is not installed in your env. Activate your env and install "aiohttp" and try again